# How can I free up space on my disk?

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

As I was attempting to update my computer from the update manager this popped up on my screen:

> Not enough disk space, the upgrade needs a total of 81.8 m free space
>   on disk' /boot '.

I emptied my trash and typed `sudo apt-get clean` into the terminal as recommended to no effect. How do I safely and easily free up space on my disk?

I have looked at other answers to similar questions and the answer are too complicated for an inexperienced fellow such as I. So to be more specific, are there any free programs I can download that will help me manage my disk space, or...

Answer (score 0):

If your `/boot` and `/` mount points point to the same partition:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

will remove all the dependencies not needed anymore.

Comment: @DavidGerstmann The linked questions contains way more methods of freeing up space, I just added what was missing in there, see the linked question for way more efficient methods.

Comment: I'm still having the same problems. "Sudo apt-get autoremove --purge" no longer works. I followed the link as suggested and it is hopelessly complicated computer speak. There has to be a simpler approach to this.